# Nested expression in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to have nested expressions in angularjs?
I tried to access a variable

like

```
{{item.{{model.key}}}}
```

where

```
item = {
    ac_no: "123"
    address: "Delhi"
    dob: "1990-02-24"
    first_name: "Joe"
    last_name: "Weller"
}
```

and

```
model.key = 'ac_no'
```

But it gave an error. How can I access a variable like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) in order to access property by variable name. In your case it will be:

```
{{ item[model.key] }}
```

Think of `item` as object with key `ac_no`. During expression evaluation the part `model.key` will resolve first to string "ac_no" which will be used after to access `item` corresponding property.

Answer (score 1):

Use bracket notation to use nested expression:

```
{{item[model.key]}}
```

Comment: should be `{{item[model.key]}}` mistakenly used `''`